# cannot change the php.ini file!

Tags: php, configuration, xampp, ini

I have changed the php.ini file in the location (C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini) for Xampp and restart the server

I am sure it is the real php.ini file because I have checked with phpinfo()

however my changes does not take effect!

why?

update:

---

I have PHP Version 5.2.8

I have changed the file C:\xampp\php\php5.ini

but the problem still the same no effects

Comment: If you are using PHP5 you have to use a php5.ini file. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: To find out the INI file that is in effect run a phpinfo(); and check the setting "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: I have checked the phpinfo and found that file (C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini) and change the setting however this didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

I used to restart the Apache using this file "xampp_restart.exe"

but now I figured out that I should right click on the file and chose "run as administrator"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that whatever change you made in php.ini is overridden at either one of 2 levels:

1. Apache virtual host setting
2. At runtime in php e.g. [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Check those out and see what you find.

What setting are you changing in php.ini?

Comment: I am trying to enable this extension (extension=php_tidy.dll) and I am sure there are NO ini_set() in my script however I don't know what does virtual host setting means but I am running XAMPP package in my laptop .note(even when I changed the memory limit it did not take effect as well!!!)